# "Elseif' not working

Tags: php, if-statement

I've made a php script based on a couple of "If" statements. $depOption can only be `bitcoin`, `ethereum`, `lisk`, `EUR` or `USD`.

The content in the `if` statement works, however the content in the elseif statements return `$VAR` as 0.

I've tested the code in these statements by themselves, and they work. Only when I put them in my elseif statements, do they not work.

```
if ($depOption == "bitcoin" or "ethereum" or "lisk")
    {

        // Get information on altcoin values
        $request = 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/';
        $response  = file_get_contents($request);
        $data = json_decode($response, true);
        $price = null;
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            if ($item["id"] == "$depOption") {
                $VAL = $item["price_usd"];
                break;
            }
        }
    }
elseif ($depOption == "EUR")
    {
        // Get EUR exchange rate
        $eurrequest = 'http://api.fixer.io/latest';
        $eurresponse  = file_get_contents($eurrequest);
        $eurdata = json_decode($eurresponse, true);
        $VAL = $eurdata['rates']['USD'];
    }

elseif ($depOption == "USD")
    {
        $VAL = 1;
    }

else
    {
        die("Something went wrong.");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is incorrect:

```
if ($depOption == "bitcoin" or "ethereum" or "lisk")
```

It's parsed as if you'd written:

```
if (($depOption == "bitcoin") or "ethereum" or "lisk")
```

Since `"ethereum"` is truthy, the `or` expression returns `true`, regardless of the value of `$depOption`. The correct way to write this is:

```
if ($depOption == "bitcoin" or $depOption == "ethereum" or $depOption == "lisk")
```

Comment: the common alternative is `if(in_array($depOption, array("bitcoin","ethereum","lisk"))` ...

Comment: Yes! This is my problem, I never knew that or looked over the whole command, thanks.